# Cast int* to const short int*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, int

I am using functions from a library where a most-important function takes arguments of type `const short int*`. What I have instead is `int *` and was wondering if there was a way of casting an `int *` into a `const short int*`. The following code snippet highlights the problem I am facing:

```
/* simple program to convert int* to const short* */


    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void disp(const short* arr, int len) {

      int i = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("ith index = %hd\n", arr[i]);
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

      int len = 10, i = 0;
      int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * len);

      for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
      }

      disp(arr, len);

      return 0;
    }
```

The above code snippet compiles.
This is what I have tried so far:
1. Tried the c-style cast. Function call looked something like so:
`disp((const short*) arr, len)`. The resulting output was quite weird:

```
ith index = 0
ith index = 0
ith index = 1
ith index = 0
ith index = 2
ith index = 0
ith index = 3
ith index = 0
ith index = 4
ith index = 0
```

1. Tried the const-ness cast. Function call looked like:
   `disp(const_cast<const short*> arr, len);`
   This resulted in an error while compiling.

My question(s):
1. Why is the output in approach 1 so weird? What is going on over there?
2. I saw some examples that remove const-ness using the const cast in approach 2. I do not know how to add the same.
3. Is there a way to cast an `int*` into a `const short int*`?

P.S: If there are questions of this sort that have been asked before, please do let me know. I googled it and did not find anything specific.

Comment: You should be aiming to remove casts from your code.

Comment: Although I have written a semblance of an answer, it would probably help if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve - this sounds like an XY question, you want to do X, which you think should be solved by Y, so therefore you ask about Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so the SIZE of a `short` is different to an `int` in many environments (it doesn't have to be, and there are certainly compilers that for example have 16-bit `int` and 16-bit `short`).

So what you get out of casting a pointer in this way is, a) undefined behaviour, and b) unless you know exactly what you are doing, probably not what you wanted anyway.

The output from your code looks perfectly fine from what I'd expect, so clearly you are not telling us something about what you are trying to do!

Edit: Note that since pointers are "size-dependant", if you cast a pointer of one size to a pointer to a type of a different size, the alignment of the data will be wrong, which is why every other value is zero in your output - because an `int` is 4 bytes [typically] and a `short` is 2 bytes, the pointer will "step" 2 bytes for each index, (so `arr[i]` will be original `arr` + i * 2 bytes. where the `int * arr` has a 'step' of 4 bytes, so `arr + i * 4` bytes. Depending on your integer values, you will get some "half an integer" values out of this - since your numbers are small, this is zero.

So, whilst the compiler is doing exactly what you ask it to do: make a pointer to `short` point to a lump of memory containing `int`, it won't do what you EXPECT it to do, namely translate each `int` into a `short`. To do that, you will either have to do:

```
short **sarr = malloc(sizof(short *) * 10); 

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sarr[i] = (short *)(&arr[i]);       // This may well not work, since you get the "wrong half" of the int.
}
```

If this gives the wrong half, you can do this:

```
     sarr[i] = (short *)(&arr[i])+1;      // Get second half of int.
```

But it depends on the "byte-order" (big endian or little endian) so it's not portable. And it's very bad coding style to do this in general code.

Or:
    short *sarr = malloc(sizof(short *) * 10);

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sarr[i] = (short)(arr[i]);
}
```

The second method works in the sense that it makes a copy of your integer array into a short array. This also doesn't depend on the order the content is stored, or anything like that. Of course, if the value in `arr[i]` is greater than what can fit in a `short`, you don't get the same value as `arr[i]` in your `short`!

And in both cases don't forget to free your array when it is no longer needed.

Comment: The code snippet reflects `precisely` what I am trying to do.. to figure out a way to cast an `int*` into a `const short int*`.

Comment: Well, then your code is working just fine - unless there is some sort of problem that you haven't described in your question.

Comment: edited the question. please let me know if that makes it more "transparent".

Comment: I've edited my reply to answer what I think is your question.

Answer (score 5):

In general, casting from `int *` to `short *` will not give useful behaviour (in fact, it will probably lead to undefined behaviour if you try to dereference the resulting pointer).  They are pointers to fundamentally different types.

If your function expects a pointer to a bunch of `short`s, then that's what you'll need to give it.  You'll need to create an array of `short`, and populate it from your original array.

Comment: ok. but won't passing `short*` when it expects `const short*` create problems? I have not tried that yet, and I will.. but wanted to ask you.

Comment: @Sriram: No, passing a `T *` to something expecting a `const T *` is totally fine (you won't even need an explicit cast).  It's the other way round that's potentially problematic.

Comment: Passing non-`const` to `const`-expecting functions is ok. The `const` keyword is sometimes used in function definitions to indicate that a specific function will not alter the parameters you give it. As an example, look at the definition for `printf` which declares it's `format` parameter as `const char*`

Answer (score 5):

Casts are almost always a sign of a design problem. If you have a function that takes a `short*` (`const` or otherwise), you need to call it with a `short*`. So instead of allocating an array of `int`, allocate an array of `short`.

When you cast an `int*` to a `short*` you're telling the compiler to pretend that the `int*` is really a pointer to `short`. It will do that, but having lied to the compiler, you're responsible for the consequences.

Comment: "Casts are almost always a sign of a design problem" - I wouldn't agree with that, it is useful and powerful feature when you *know* what you are doing.

Comment: It depends on the type of case, no?  I don't see any problem of using `static_cast` to convert a narrow arithmetic type to a wider one, or an `int` to a `doubled`.  Pointer casts, on the other hand are a different issue, and I'd agree with you on that.

Comment: "`static_cast` to convert a narrow arithmetic type to a wider one": that is, add an explicit cast to tell the compiler to do a safe, well-defined conversion that it would do anyway? Such a cast provides no benefit, and could mask a problem introduced in a later maintenance cycle.

Comment: The one systematic exception I can think of off-hand is downcasting from a base class pointer.

Comment: @Agentlien - even then. `<g>` In most cases, needing a cast within a hierarchy indicates a design problem. Occasionally, okay, but for beginners, a stronger rule is appropriate: don't use casts.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to q.1**
The output is not weird at all. Apparently, your compiler assign each `int` 4 bytes and each `short` 2 bytes. Therefore, your `arr` is of size 10x4 = 40 bytes. When you assign numbers 0..9 to it you have in memory (one char per byte, grouped by `int` ):

> 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 1
>   0 0 0 2
>   0 0 0 3
>   0 0 0 4
>   ...

When you cast `arr` to `short` the memory is now "grouped" into 2 bytes :

> 0 0
>   0 0
>   0 0
>   0 1
>   0 0
>   0 2
>   0 0
>   ...

I hope you can see the effect, and why you suddenly have `0`-s in between the numbers you assigned.

**Answer to q.2**
The declaration of `const` in the function `display` only means that the content of `arr` will not be changed during the execution of `display`. You do not need to explicitly cast the argument to `const` array in order to invoke `display`.

**Answer to q.3**
please see answers by @Pete and @Mats